# How does List<T>.Find work when T is a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, struct

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, othertype>>`. I need to do something along the lines of

```
list.Find(x=>x.Key=="foobar")
```

However, if that doesn't exist in the list, what will the behavior be? Usually it would return null, but structs can't be null.

Comment: Try it with `int` and see what happens.

Comment: The default value for type T, more specifically `default(T)`.

Comment: If you want Find to return null when no match is found, consider using Tuple instead of KeyValuePair.

Comment: @JamieSee Can't use Tuples because we are aiming for .Net 2.0 compatibility

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will return the `default(T)` which will be the same as `new KeyValuePair<string, othertype>>()`, that is, a default initialized struct.

Basically, the default for reference types is always `null`, and for value types (including `struct`) it's the default (`0` for numerics, `false` for `bool`, a `struct` with every field defaulted for structures, etc.)

So, for a `default(KeyValuePair<string, othertype>>)` you'd get back a KVP where the `Key` was `null` (default for `string`) and whatever the `default(othertype)` would be (as in the examples above)...

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx):

> The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified
>   predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T.

Using this, if you wanted to check and see if you got back the `default`, I'd recommend checking for `yourResult.Key != null` to see if you got a result, or you could use a different `Find` method such as `FindIndex` as Olivier suggests.

Comment: It may be worth noting that for the particular value type `Nullable<T>`, because the default initialization results in `HasValue` being false (as would be any Boolean field of any structure), it causes the structure to be interpreted in many contexts as a null value.

Answer (score 21):

My advice is to use `FindIndex` for non nullable types

```
int index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Key == "foobar");
if (index >= 0) {
    // found!
    UseResult(list[index]);
}
```

The default value `default(T)` is returned if `Find()` is not successful. For non nullable types, this result cannot be distinguished from regular entries having the default value. This is also true for nullable types when the list might contain regular `null` entries.

Comment: +1: this is the better solution.  In this case, a key-value pair with a null key is unlikely to be a legitimate value, but it is possible.  Far too many people forget this, or that, for example, a `List<string>` can contain null values.

Comment: +1: Very nice. I didn't want to compare against a default; like you said, in most cases, there's no way to determine the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Structure is a value type. so, In case of structure Find will return default value of structure.

**EXAMPLE:**

Lets say we have structure as below,

```
public struct Test
{
   public int i;
}

List<Test> list = new List<test>() { new Test { i = 1 } };
Test result = list.Find(o => o.i == 2);
```

In above Find result value like new Test(). you can compare value by below code.

```
if (resul.Equals(new Test()))
{

        //Do something
 }
 else
 {
                  //Do something    
 }
```

**OR**

```
if (resul.Equals(default(Test)))
{

        //Do something
 }
 else
 {
                  //Do something    
 }
```

Comment: Heh, that if condition looks so... wrong. That would never ever work for reference types :) structs are definitely not something I use everyday though

Comment: I'd recommend against doing a `== new Test()`, that's a bit heavy since `==` on `struct` is reflective.  I'd instead recommend checking the `Key` field for `null` in the `OP` example.

Comment: Yes we can check Key field for null. But I think if key type is int then default value for int is 0. so, if we don't want to go with data type then checking with new Test() will be useful.

Comment: Even in those cases, I'd check default(Test) rather than == new Test(), intention is more clear.

Comment: Okay. thanks @JamesMichaelHare after read about default(T)  default(Test) looks better than new Test()

Answer (score 1):

By reading these two documentation articles, it sounds to me as though you should be returned the default value for your struct:

Default Values:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475(v=vs.71).aspx

List(T).Find Method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx